# Is there an elegant way to have conda install a 3rd party golang package during a docker build?

Tags: docker, go, conda

I’m preparing a docker image w/ Ubuntu v18.04 for s/w development. I’m including miniconda to manage the development environment, which is all golang. I [create the environment with a YAML file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file):

```
RUN conda env create --file goDev.yml
```

I’d also like the conda environment to be activated when the docker is started. That’s a little tricky to do b/c conda has to be initialized first, but [JaegerP](https://github.com/JaegerP) provides a nice workaround [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/89) that involves updating .bashrc (thanks).

Unfortunately, I also need to install [a third party YAML package](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to golang. I have to activate the environment to install the package, so it brings me back to the original problem [JaegerP](https://github.com/JaegerP) helped me overcome: I can’t activate the environment until its initialized, and I cannot initialize during the docker build b/c I have to restart the shell.

In other words, this works nicely:

> RUN conda env create --file goDev.yml 
> && rm goDev.yml 
> && echo "source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" 
> && echo "conda activate go_dev" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc

The desired conda environment is activated when the docker is started, unfortunately the external YAML package is not installed. This does not work b/c the conda environment can't be activated until it's initialized and initialization requires the shell to be restarted:

> RUN conda env create --file goDev.yml 
> && rm goDev.yml 
> && conda init bash 
> && conda activate go_dev 
> && go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2 
> && echo "source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" 
> && echo "conda activate go_dev" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc

I could update .bashrc further to install the YAML package if this file doesn’t exist:

```
/root/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/gopkg.in/yaml.v2
```

Is there a more elegant solution that enables me to install a 3rd party golang package during the docker build instead of checking for it each time the image is run?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing what's going wrong?  Usually you do in fact download and install Go packages during the build phase (using Go's native packaging tools, you'll frequently see `RUN go mod download` to separate dependency installation from actually building the binary).

Comment: Thanks @David-Maze. I’m creating my conda environment w/ a yaml file. I want to update golang within the environment to include a third party, so I need to activate the environment. If you do that, conda complains that the environment must be initialized and the docker build is interrupted. A single command:

RUN conda env create --file goDev.yml \
    && conda init bash \
    && conda activate go_dev \
    && go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2

doesn't work b/c the shell has to be restarted for the initialization to work. The work around is to update .bashrc

Comment: It would be better to include code from the Dockerfile *in the question*. Have you tried something like `RUN . /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate yourenv && do_some_go_stuff ...`? Also, I highly recommend reading [this blog post](https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html) by one of the core Conda devs.

Comment: Docker doesn't usually run shell dot files at all, and environment managers like Conda can be tricky to run there.  I usually see them around Python applications where Anaconda has a separate package repository.  But for Go applications, you shouldn't need this at all; just start a Dockerfile `FROM golang:1.17` and `RUN go get` (or `go mod download`) the stuff you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try Conda Run

The `conda run` function provides a clean way to run code within an environment context without having to manually activate. Try something like

```
RUN conda env create --file goDev.yml 
  && rm goDev.yml 
  && conda run -n go_dev go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2 
  && echo '. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate go_dev' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

Also, you probably want to end all RUN chains involving Conda with

```
conda clean -qafy
```

to keep help minimize Docker image layer size.

Comment: Thanks @merv! BTW, the "conda clean -qafy" directive saved ~700MB of space. Honorable mention to @David-Maze for his suggestion that sidesteps the issue by creating a simpler docker that supports only go - hadn't thought of that...